# Почему jQuery не выполняет условие?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

может кто то объяснить, почему не работает `$('..').css()`

Поставил `id` только для проверки, так же не работает на все `span` и так далее.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    angular.module('profilePage').component('profilePage', {
    templateUrl: 'app/components/profile-page/profile-page.template.html',
    controller: ['$http', '$scope', function ProfilePageController($http, $scope){

        var account_id = 131389547;
        var api_key = '706700BD62A6A2A65A14C30E3D1A7260';



        $http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : 'https://api.opendota.com/api/players/' + account_id + '/',
            params: {
                'api_key' : api_key
            }
    }).then(function success(response){

        $scope.data = response.data;
        $scope.profile = response.data.profile;
        console.log(response.data);
        $scope.rank = response.data.rank_tier;

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '../assets/medal.json'
        }).then(function(ranks){
            $scope.medal = ranks.data;
            console.log($scope.rank);
            console.log($scope.medal);
            console.log($scope.medal.ranks.length);
            for(let rk = 0; rk < ranks.data.ranks.length; rk++){
                if($scope.rank == $scope.medal.ranks[rk].id){
                    $scope.rank = $scope.medal.ranks[rk].image;
                    console.log($scope.rank);
                }

            };

        }, function(ranks){

        })

        $http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : 'https://api.opendota.com/api/players/' + account_id + '/peers',
            params: {
                'api_key' : api_key
            }
        }).then(function(profilepeers){
            $scope.profilepeer = profilepeers.data;
            for(let peer = 0; peer < $scope.profilepeer.length; peer++){
                $scope.profilepeer[peer].win_rate_peer = ($scope.profilepeer[peer].with_win / $scope.profilepeer[peer].with_games)*100;
            };

            console.log($scope.profilepeer);
        }, function(profilepeer){

        });


    }, function failed(response) {
        alert('Bad request!');
    })




    $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : 'https://api.opendota.com/api/players/' + account_id + '/wl',
        params: {
            'api_key' : api_key
        }
    }).then(function success(winlose){

        $scope.stats = winlose.data;
        console.log(winlose);
        $scope.winrate = ($scope.stats.win / ($scope.stats.win + $scope.stats.lose))*100;



    }, function failed(winlose) {
        alert('Bad request!');
    })



    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.opendota.com/api/players/' + account_id +'/recentmatches',
        params: {
            'api_key': api_key
        }
    }).then(function success(response){
        $scope.matches = response.data;
        console.log($scope.matches);



        for(let wl = 0; wl < $scope.matches.length; wl++){
            if($scope.matches[wl].radiant_win == true && $scope.matches[wl].player_slot <= 127){
                $scope.matches[wl].radiant_win = 'win';
            } else if ($scope.matches[wl].radiant_win == false && $scope.matches[wl].player_slot <= 127) {
                $scope.matches[wl].radiant_win = 'lose';
            } else if ($scope.matches[wl].radiant_win == true && $scope.matches[wl].player_slot >= 128) {
                $scope.matches[wl].radiant_win = 'lose';
            } else if ($scope.matches[wl].radiant_win == false && $scope.matches[wl].player_slot >= 128) {
                $scope.matches[wl].radiant_win = 'win';
            }
        };



        for(let q = 0; q < response.data.length; q++){
            if($scope.matches[q].skill == '0'){
                $scope.matches[q].skill = 'Unknow';
            } else if($scope.matches[q].skill == '1'){
                $scope.matches[q].skill = 'Normal Skill';
            } else if($scope.matches[q].skill == '2'){
                $scope.matches[q].skill = 'High Skill';
            } else if($scope.matches[q].skill == '3'){
                $scope.matches[q].skill = 'Very High Skill';
            }
        };

        for(let cls = 0; cls < $scope.matches.length; cls++){
            console.log($scope.matches[cls].radiant_win);
            if($scope.matches[cls].radiant_win == 'win'){
                $("#winlose").css("color", "green");
            } else if($scope.matches[cls].radiant_win == 'lose'){
                $("#winlose").css("color", "red");
            }
        };

        for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++){
            $scope.matches[i].duration = Math.ceil($scope.matches[i].duration / 60) + ':' + Math.ceil($scope.matches[i].duration % 60);
            if ($scope.matches[i].game_mode == '0') {
                $scope.matches[i].game_mode = 'No Game Mode';
            } else if ($scope.matches[i].game_mode == '1') {
                $scope.matches[i].game_mode = 'All Pick';
            } else if ($scope.matches[i].game_mode == '2') {
                $scope.matches[i].game_mode = "Captain's Mode";
            } else if ($scope.matches[i].game_mode == '3') {
                $scope.matches[i].game_mode = 'Random Draft';
            } else if ($scope.matches[i].game_mode == '4') {
                $scope.matches[i].game_mode = 'Single Draft';
            } else if ($scope.matches[i].game_mode == '5') {
                $scope.matches[i].game_mode = 'All Random';
            } else if ($scope.matches[i].game_mode == '6') {
                $scope.matches[i].game_mode = 'Intro';
            } else if ($scope.matches[i].game_mode == '7') {
                $scope.matches[i].game_mode = "Diretide";
            } else if ($scope.matches[i].game_mode == '8') {
                $scope.matches[i].game_mode = "Reverse Captain's Mode";
            } else if ($scope.matches[i].game_mode == '9') {
                $scope.matches[i].game_mode = 'Greeviling';
            } else if ($scope.matches[i].game_mode == '10') {
                $scope.matches[i].game_mode = 'Tutorial';
            } else if ($scope.matches[i].game_mode == '11') {
                $scope.matches[i].game_mode = 'Mid Only';
            } else if ($scope.matches[i].game_mode == '12') {
                $scope.matches[i].game_mode = 'Least Played';
            } else if ($scope.matches[i].game_mode == '13') {
                $scope.matches[i].game_mode = 'New Player Pool';
            } else if ($scope.matches[i].game_mode == '14') {
                $scope.matches[i].game_mode = 'Compendium Matchmaking';
            } else if ($scope.matches[i].game_mode == '15') {
                $scope.matches[i].game_mode = "Custom";
            } else if ($scope.matches[i].game_mode == '16') {
                $scope.matches[i].game_mode = "Captain's Draft";
            } else if ($scope.matches[i].game_mode == '17') {
                $scope.matches[i].game_mode = 'Balanced Draft';
            } else if ($scope.matches[i].game_mode == '18') {
                $scope.matches[i].game_mode = 'Ability Draft';
            } else if ($scope.matches[i].game_mode == '19') {
                $scope.matches[i].game_mode = 'Custom Game';
            } else if ($scope.matches[i].game_mode == '20') {
                $scope.matches[i].game_mode = 'All Random Deathmatch';
            } else if ($scope.matches[i].game_mode == '21') {
                $scope.matches[i].game_mode = 'Solo Mid 1v1';
            } else if ($scope.matches[i].game_mode == '22') {
                $scope.matches[i].game_mode = 'Ranked All Pick';
            }
            else if ($scope.matches[i].game_mode == '23') {
                $scope.matches[i].game_mode = 'Turbo';
            } 
        };




        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '../assets/heroes.json'
        }).then(function success(heroes){
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(heroes.data));
            $scope.hero = heroes.data;
            for(let k = 0; k < response.data.length; k++){
                for (n = 0; n < heroes.data.length; n++){
                    if ($scope.matches[k].hero_id == $scope.hero[n].id) {
                        $scope.matches[k].hero_id = $scope.hero[n].localized_name;
                        $scope.matches[k].url = $scope.hero[n].url;
                        // console.log($scope.matches);
                    }
                }
            }


            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'https://api.opendota.com/api/players/' + account_id + '/heroes',
                params: {
                    'api_key': api_key
                }
            }).then(function(bestHeroes){
                $scope.bestHero = bestHeroes.data;
                console.log($scope.bestHero)
                for(let f = 0; f < bestHeroes.data.length; f++){
                    for(let n = 0; n < heroes.data.length; n++){
                        if($scope.bestHero[f].hero_id == $scope.hero[n].id){
                            $scope.bestHero[f].hero_id = $scope.hero[n].localized_name;
                            $scope.bestHero[f].url = $scope.hero[n].url;
                            $scope.bestHero[f].win_rate = ($scope.bestHero[f].win / $scope.bestHero[f].games) * 100 + '%';
                        }
                    }
                };
                }, function failed(bestHeroes){

            })

        }, function failed(heroes){

        })

    }, function failed(response){

    });

        (function($){
          $(function() {
            $('.menu__icon').on('click', function() {
              $(this).closest('.menu').toggleClass('menu_state_open');
            });
          });
        })(jQuery);


        $(".function-content a").click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(".function-content a").removeClass('chosen');
          $(this).addClass('chosen');
        });

}]
}).filter('firstWord', firstWord).filter('other', other);

    firstWord.$inject = ['$filter'];
    other.$inject = ['$filter'];


    function firstWord($filter) {
        return function(data) {
            if(!data) return data;
            data = data.split(' ');
            return data[0];
        };
    };
    function other($filter) {
        return function(data) {
            if(!data) return data;
            data = data.split(' ').slice(1,3).join(' ');
            return data;

        };
    };
```

Comment: Видимый цвет `#winlose` будет установлен в последней итерации цикла. Вы этого и хотели?

Comment: @Igor все 20 элементов выведены, цвет остается белым. Цикл в консоли проходит нормально. Либо я не понимаю до конца, что вы имели в виду

Comment: какие значения выводятся в консоль?

Comment: @Igor `lose / win` в зависимости от того, где какое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Два варианта.

Первый.

Код на картинке находится внутри обработчика, выполняемого в процессе сабмита формы или GET-перехода на эту же самую страницу, и Вы не успеваете увидеть изменений  стилей.

Второй.

В сравниваемых строках смешаны латинские буквы и кириллица. Визуально одинаковые строки одинаковыми не являются.

---

Хорошо, предположим DOM-элементов в выборке `$(".span-winlose")` столько же сколько объектов в массиве `$scope.matches`:

```
    for(let cls = 0; cls < $scope.matches.length; cls++){
        console.log($scope.matches[cls].radiant_win);
        if($scope.matches[cls].radiant_win == 'win'){
            $(".span-winlose").eq(cls).css("color", "green");
        } else if($scope.matches[cls].radiant_win == 'lose'){
            $(".span-winlose").eq(cls).css("color", "red");
        }
    };
```

Comment: Скорее всего это первый вариант, но если вынести этот код за пределы запросов, он перестает работать, мало того, он ломает полностью все `ng-repeat` и `ng-bind` - как это можно исправить?

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич Мне было бы гораздо легче, если бы Вы включили в вопрос код, а не картинки. Где он все-таки находится?

Comment: но код большой, сразу предупреждаю(

Comment: свичем чуть позже переделаю огромный кусок if else

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич хм, ничего не бросается в глаза. Не может этот кусок DOM-а переписываться в одном из `$http().then`?

Comment: нет, я проверял, я попробую еще класс добавить, но сомневаюсь что это решит проблему. У меня так же в этом проекте много странностей - например это `https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/891384/template-в-component-ведет-себя-очень-странно`

Comment: класс меняет цвет, но всех, не зависимо от результата цикла...

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич минутку. Не понял последнюю фразу.

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич Сколько у Вас элементов с `id="#winlose"`, какой результат Вы ожидаете, и какой - наблюдаете?

Comment: если задать в css доп. класс и стили для него, и `$(".span-winlose").toggleClass("lose");` то цвет изменится на красный(указывал красный). Но изменится у всех span не зависимо от условия в цикле. То есть совпадает оно или нет.

Comment: 20 элементов, каждый из которых получает значение из массива, и выводит это значение. В цикле я сверяю эти значения, если сходится должен получить нужный мне цвет. В моем случае `win = green`/ `lose=red`.

Но в итоге я вижу что все меняют цвет не зависимо от условия.

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич А-а-а-а. Как Вы выбираете элемент, у которого хотите сменить цвет в данной итерации цикла?

Comment: Ну если значение в массиве данного объекта ( в моем случае `$scope.matches[cls].radiant_win` ) совпадает с нужным мне значением, то я хочу поменять цвет на нужный мне. ( [cls] - переменная цикла )

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич Как Вы выбираете DOM-элемент с помощью jQuery?

Comment: вот тут у меня и видимо проблема, потому что я не совсем представляю, в таком случае, как выбрать соответствующий дом элемент

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич Как соотносятся элемент массива, который Вы проверяете `$scope.matches[cls]`, и DOM-элемент, цвет которого Вы хотите изменить?

Comment: я думаю по index но могу ошибиться

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич Добавил в ответ.

Comment: спасибо огромное за помощь, не работало, пока не поставил в самый верхний запрос, но все равно огромное спасибо!